# Regex to remove certain patterns from urls

Tags: nginx, rewrite, 301-redirect

So i've tried this multiple times but to no avail.

Basically, what I am trying to do is check if the URL has a certain language locale and remove it and do a 301 redirect to the parent url without the locale. For example, I have...

```
www.domain.com/mx/en-us/product/asset/23456768
www.domain.com/de/en-gb/product/asset/34565768
www.domain.com/ar/en-us/product/asset/34567788
www.domain.com/ar/en-us/affiliates
```

The pattern I would like to remove is any case of **/en-us** or **/en-gb**. So the new urls would look like...

```
www.domain.com/mx/product/asset/23456768
www.domain.com/de/product/asset/34565768
www.domain.com/ar/product/asset/34567788
www.domain.com/ar/affiliates
```

I have this, but its not working in NGINX

```
server {
    rewrite ^/en-us(.*)$ $1 last;
    rewrite ^/en-gb(.*)$ $1 last;
    return 301;
  }
```

Am I missing something? Should I not be using rewrite? Also can this be done in one line?

Comment: Hi ! for any edit please log to your account, and it will allow you to comment to people on your own post too. Thanks for your understanding !

Answer (score 1):

If all your URIs should match the pattern you given (two letter prefix before the locale part):

```
rewrite "^(/\w{2})/en-(?:us|gb)(/.*)" $1$2 permanent;
```

(regex pattern should be quoted due to the curly braces usage)

If such a prefix length can vary:

```
rewrite ^(/\w+)/en-(?:us|gb)(/.*) $1$2 permanent;
```

To match the locale part everywhere:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/en-(?:us|gb)/(.*) $1/$2 permanent;
```